# Display custom entities using diSplacy

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a text string with a set of *fixed* named entities (person, location, ...) as shown in the example below

```py
text = "My name is John Smith and I live in Paris"
entities = [
    ("Person", 11, 21),  # John Smith
    ("Location", 36, 41),  # Paris
]
```

and I would like to display them using the very nice renderer from Spacy called DiSplacy [1].
If I understand well, the best way for me is to create a custom `Doc` object in Spacy using my custom entities but I didn't find the right way to do this.

[1] https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#ent

Comment: Do you want to detect custom entities or just display them using DiSplacy?

Comment: Run a Jupyter notebook, and use `displacy.render(nlp(text),style="ent",jupyter=True)`

Comment: Or do you mean you cannot create the document object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution in Spacy forums (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7239).

In a nutshell, Doc can be easily instantiated with entities in spacy 3.0+. In Spacy 2.0+ (my case) a solution is to use `char_span`:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")

text = "My name is John Smith and I live in Paris"
entities = [
    ("Employee", 11, 21),  # John Smith
    ("Location", 36, 41),  # Paris
]

doc = nlp(text)

ents = []
for ee in entities:
    ents.append(doc.char_span(ee[1], ee[2], ee[0]))

doc.ents = ents

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent, ent.label_, sep="\t")
```

Comment: what would be solution for `spacy 3.0+`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the manual option in `displacy.serve()` or `displacy.render()`.

```py
dic_ents = {
    "text": "My name is John Smith and I live in Paris",
    "ents": [
        {"start": 11, "end": 21, "label": "Person"},
        {"start": 36, "end": 41, "label": "Location"},
    ],
    "title": None
}

displacy.render(dic_ents, manual=True, style="ent")
```

Answer (score 0):

To render the visualization, you can use the ipython mode of displacy.render function.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

from spacy import displacy

dic_ents = {
    "text": "My name is John Smith and I live in Paris",
    "ents": [
        {"start": 11, "end": 21, "label": "Person"},
        {"start": 36, "end": 41, "label": "Location"},
    ],
    "title": None
}

html = displacy.render(dic_ents, manual=True, style="ent")
display(HTML(html))
```